# Is there a fluid simulation update/re-write on the horizon?

Tags: node-editor, particles, fluid-simulation

Blender's fluid simulation has seen very little love or significant advancement in recent times.  So, with the particle re-write and the 'nodifying' of simulations, will there be attention given to updating the code and algorithms for fluids?  Maybe even using GPU computational power?  There's a lot of much needed change coming to Blender, so I had to ask on this front.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's is a question about the development plans instead of Blender it's self.

Comment: Hi, this isn't really the right place to be asking about this type of thing. I'd recommend that you ask this either on the #blendercoders irc channel, or on the Blender Mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Manta Flow Project included on the GSOC 2014:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Romanp/GSoC_Mantaflow_Framework/Docs

But it seems that the project has been abandoned.